# Get Windows 7, InstallShield, MDAC 2.7, and (shudder) VB6 playing nicely

Tags: windows-7, installshield

**Short version:**
When I moved to Win7, I manually removed the MDAC 2.7 lines from my .ISM module, built it, and installed my software. It seems to work. Can I trust it?

**Longer version:**
We have just gone from XP to Windows 7. The software we deliver is C# (.NET 4 framework), targeting XP and Windows 7. It contains a few older COM modules, one of which is written in VB6. (Yes, I would love to rewrite this in a modern technology, but that's not an option at this point.)

I use InstallShield 2010 to build the installer for this package. Building this installer on XP worked with no problems. When I try on Windows 7, it wants MDAC 2.7 as a prerequisite merge module. Microsoft doesn't allow you to download 2.7 anymore, and I'm not going to get it from "Sharewarez R'us" sites.

The error InstallShield gave me when it couldn't find the merge module was: `File not found. An error occured merging Module 'MDAC27ENU...'`

From what I've read on the web, Windows 7 has the latest-greatest MDAC (now renamed WDAC) already installed. On a whim, I manually deleted the MDAC dependencies from the .ISM, built and installed, and my software **seemed** to run just fine.

What I think is happening is Win7 is noticing that something in VB6 is using MDAC and the OS is supplying the latest-greatest and it just works. I no longer need the merge module because Windows 7 has WDAC built in. (Can it really be that simple?)

My main question is: can I trust it?

My secondary question is: What about XP deployments? They will still need MDAC 2.7... Does that indicate I can't build on Windows 7 to target XP if I require MDAC 2.7?  Please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a comprehensive review (dependency analysis) of your installer.   The VB6 runtime and MDAC/WDAC components are all built into windows these days.  This is also the case with Windows XP and the latest service pack.

Either your ISM is referencing the MDAC merge module or it's referencing another merge module that has a dependency on the MDAC merge module.  Hence why I suggest a complete review.

Without looking at your application I can't give you a 100% answer but odds are that if you implement a setup condition (launch condition) to check for XP latest service pack or newer  that you will likely work without installing a bunch of stuff you don't need to be installing.

Comment: I went back to an XP machine, removed the MDAC lines and had similar success. It really was a false dependency--boy do I feel sheepish. This false dependency has been around for a VERY long time. Thanks for the good advice.

Comment: Ya, it's rare for people to go back and clean up the old stuff. The focus is always on the new technology.